# How to join queries with a subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subquery

So I'm a total newbie trying to solve this exercise where I have to find all the dishes that are marked as *Vegetarian* but contain *Turkey meat* in their ingredients.

This is what I've tried (this is where I inner join 3 tables to find the ingredients):

```
SELECT Name
FROM Dishes
INNER JOIN DishesIngredients ON DishesIngredients.DishId = s.Id
INNER JOIN Ingredients ON DishesIngredients.IngredientID = Ingredients.ID
```

this is where I can't seem to be able to join the subquery to identify the Vegetarian tag:

```
WHERE Ingredients.Name = 'Turkey meat' =
(SELECT Name
FROM Tags
INNER JOIN DishesTags ON DishesTags.TagID = Tags.ID
INNER JOIN Dishes ON DishesTags.DishID = Dishes.ID)
```

The diagram of the database is here for reference:

[image: The diagram of the database is here for reference]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let first find out how many dishes have Turkey meat as ingredient.

You have:

```
SELECT D.ID
FROM
Dishes D 
JOIN DishIngredients DI ON D.ID = DI.DishID
JOIN Ingredients I ON DI.IngredientID = I.ID
WHERE I.Name LIKE 'Turkey meat'
```

Then get all dishes with tag 'Vegetarian'.

```
SELECT D.ID
FROM
Dishes D 
JOIN DishIngredients DI ON D.ID = DI.DishID
JOIN Ingredients I ON DI.IngredientID = I.ID
JOIN DishesTags DT on D.ID = DT.DishID
JOIN Tags T ON DT.TagID = T.ID

WHERE I.Name LIKE 'Turkey meat'
AND T.Name = 'Vegetarian'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `exists` and subqueries:

```
select d.*
from dishes d
where
    exists (
        select 1 
        from dishestags dt
        innerjoin tags t on t.id = dt.tagid
        where dt.dishid = d.id and t.name = 'Vegetarian'
    )
    and exists (
        select 1 
        from dishesingredients di
        inner join ingredients i on i.id = di.ingredientid
        where di.dishid = d.id and i.name = 'Turkey'
    )
```